# Why can't I pass a dictionary with an enum key in a Notification

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter

I tried passing a dictionary with an `enum` as key in a `Notification` (`[TestEnum: String]`). Unfortunately, type-casting the dictionary to `[TestEnum: String]` fails after receiving the notification.

```
enum TestEnum {
    case test
}

class NotificationTest {

    var sender: String = "" {
        didSet {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "Test"), object: nil, userInfo: [TestEnum.test: "test"])
        }
    }

    init() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(notificationReceived(_:)), name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "Test"), object: nil)
    }

    @objc func notificationReceived(_ notification: Notification) {
        print("Notification Received")
        guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo as? [TestEnum: String] else { return } // Type casting fails here even though userInfo shows a TestEnum key in debugger
        print(userInfo[.test])
    }

}

let test = NotificationTest()
test.sender = "blah"
```

However, if i use `rawValue` of `TestEnum` as key, it works fine when `notification.userInfo` is casted to `[String: String]`.

Comment: right, the real problem is with casting `AnyHashable` to your enum as I found in some other post. Look at Ricky's right answer. ;)

Comment: @RobertDresler maybe you could link the post?

Comment: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7049

Comment: I suppose you are trying to make your notification type-safe in strongly typed swift world. If that's the case I recommend you look at [this](http://aplus.rs/2017/type-safe-notification-handling-in-swift/) great write up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just had a look at the source code of `AnyHashable`, when you cast a `Hashable` (your enum) to `AnyHashable`, it is wrapped in the property `base` within `AnyHashable`. Therefore, it cannot be directly cast back to your enum. Here uses `reduce` to transform `[AnyHashable:Any]` to `[TestEnum:String]`:

```
@objc func notificationReceived(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("Notification Received")
    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo?.reduce(into: [TestEnum:String](), { (result, entry) in
        if let key = entry.key.base as? TestEnum
        {
            result[key] = entry.value as? String
        }
    }) else {
        print(notification.userInfo)
        return
    } // Type casting fails here even though userInfo shows a TestEnum key in debugger
    print(userInfo[.test])
}
```

And because `AnyHashable` conforms to `CustomStringConvertible`, it can be cast to `String` directly.

Comment: The last line of the answer was what i was looking for! Thanks. :)